# How do I regex search in x and y for a, and only include the replacement of y if a was found in x?

Tags: regex

I need to search through a larger text file.

This is an example of what I'm searching through.

https://pastebin.com/JFVy2TEt

```
recipes.addShaped("basemetals:adamantine_arrow", <basemetals:adamantine_arrow> * 4, [[<ore:nuggetAdamantine>], [<basemetals:adamantine_rod>], [<minecraft:feather>]]);
```

I need to look for lines that match a specific part in the first argument.

For example the "_arrow" part in the above line.

And erase everything that doesn't match on the "_arrow" in the first argument.

And the arguments differ across all of them.

And also with different names in the place where "basemetals:adamantine" is in the above line.

And since the further arguments are all different I can't wrap my head around on how to include the end only when the first thing matches.

Edit: The end goal being to ease sort my 3k+ line text file.

basic, blacksmith, carpenter, chef, chemist, engineer, farmer, jeweler, mage, mason, scribe, tailor

Comment: You forgot to mention what programming language and regex library you're using. (Regexes themselves don't even have a concept of "replace", that's just something that regexes are often used as part of.)

Comment: You should post your attempt and what you are currently getting as a result. And given the line you posted in your question, you should post what you expect the output to be; specifically for that line because `basic, blacksmith..` is not it (unless somehow it is)

Comment: I can't figure out what you're trying to do. How does that first line relate to the final result you're trying to get? Nothing in that last line looks like it comes from that `recipes.addShaped()` call.

Comment: And I don't know what "ease sort" means. Do you mean "to sort my file more easily"?

Comment: Are you just trying to extract the word "adamantine" from that line?

Comment: None of the words in the last line of the question appear anywhere in the pastebin file.

Comment: I don't want to extract a specific word.

I want to erase the lines that don't contain a word in a specific spot.

Such as erasing all the lines that don't contain "_gear" in the first argument.

Lines that match, replace with themselves.
Lines that don't match, replace with a blank space.

And it is in gedit and/or Atom text editors I am trying to do this.

To match like I want in and of its self I can do.

It's figuring out how to erase the lines that don't match while keeping the ones that do that I can't do.

Comment: I mentally freeze up in anxiety when I actually try to figure it out.
I left something out of the thing at the end.
The end goal is to make it easier to sort the lines into those categories by extracting only the lines that contain the part type I'm wanting to categorize at the time.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think what you're trying to do is filter your text file by removing lines that don't fit a set criteria. I've chosen the Atom text editor for this solution (because I'm running Windows OS and can't install gedit, and I want to ensure you have a working example).

To remove only lines that don't have a first argument ending in `_arrow`, one could do [`(?!recipes\.addShaped\("[^"]+_arrow")recipes.+\r?\n?`](https://regex101.com/r/ezsPxu/1/) and replace with nothing.

As a note: this task is made more difficult by Atom's low regex support. In a more well-supported environment, my answer would probably be `^recipes\.addShaped("[^"]+(?<!_arrow)").+\r?\n?` (with multiline mode).

Also, please read ["What should I do when someone answers my question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

**Regex explained:**

- `(?!` `)` is a [negative lookahead](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-disambiguation.html#lookarounds), which peeks at the succeeding text to ensure it doesn't contain "`_arrow`" at end of the first argument.
- `\.` is an [escaped](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character) literal period
- `[^"]` is a character class that signifies a character that is **not** a `"`.
- `+` is a quantifier which tells the regex to match the preceding character or subexpression as many times as possible, with a minimum of one time.
- `.` is a wildcard, representing any character
- `\r?\n?` is used to match any kind of newline, with the `?` quantifier making each character optional.
- Everything else it literal characters; it represents exactly what it matches.